# Installed Android Studio on Windows 10 can't be opened by regular (non-admin) AD user

Tags: windows-10, android-studio

Our company just started deploying Windows 10 workstations (replacing Windows 7).  Windows 10 doesn't allow installing anything without 'local admin' privilege.

I have issues with Android Studio 3.3. After installation, each time I start Android Studio as a non-admin regular user, its asks for admin ID and password.

Here are the detail steps of reproduction:

1. Download Android Studio 3.3 install package (android-studio-ide-182.5199772-windows.exe) from https://developer.android.com/studio/ as a regular (non-admin) user.
2. Shift + Right-click on the downloaded package and selected 'Run as different user'.
3. Enter admin user name and password and install (no issue).
4. An icon of AS appears on the desktop with a 'shield' sign (admin privileged app) on it.
5. Click on the icon; it asks for the admin user ID and password.

I need to start the AS as a regular (non-admin) user.  How can I do this ?

Comment: Is this machine connected to an Active Directory domain or commercial network?  Please edit your question and provide the necessary information required to answer your question.

Comment: Yes, to perform my work, I need to connect the machine to my company's AD domain and both 'local admin' and 'regular user' (non-admin) are in the same AD domain.

Comment: I think the problem is caused by running the installer as an another user while logged in as a different user.  The only other explanation is that Android Studio actually requires Administrator permissions.  I would uninstall Android Studio, log in as the Administrator, and install it again picking the option to install it for everyone.  If that works I will formulate an answer (or find a duplicate).  As always edit your question instead of submitting a comment providing this vital information

Comment: As suggested, I have done: 0) Uninstalled AS, 1) Logged in as admin, 2) Downloaded a fresh copy of AS install package (.exe), 3) Installed as admin, 4) Changed security of AS app (by admin) to grant all user of the machine with 'full control', 5) Logged back as regular user --< and luck ! It stills needs admin user and its password.

Comment: I would try the following.  On a Windows 10 machine not connected to the domain after installing Android Studio as a local Administrator, check if the problem exists with a local non-privileged user.  This will confirm if the domain is the problem.

Comment: Sorry for not to mention earlier, the suggested uninstall thru installation process was done on 'non-domain' environment (it was on my home network, NOT company's network and not connected over any VPN). No luck yet !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88606/discussion-between-ramhound-and-jamil-rahman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by following the instructions [here](https://androidforums.com/threads/how-to-install-android-studio-without-admin-rights.1199946):

> 1. Go here: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads
> 2. Download the zip file which says "No Android SDK, no installer"
> 3. After that, open the downloaded zip file and open the folder "bin"
> 4. Then there should be a file called "studio64.exe" (or "studio32.exe") This is basically the launcher, so just click on it,
>      and Android Studio will open!

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question and posting the solution.  Two days after posting the question, you can accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.  That's how we indicate that the problem has been solved (rather than the "Resolved" label in the title).  It will also indicate that there is a proven answer here.